# swift generics: append not found for array

Tags: swift, generics, realm, realm-list

My first attempt to use swift generics:

```
extension RealmSwift.List where Element == Object {
    // @deprecated use RealmSwift.List<>
    func arrayo<T: Object>() -> [T] {
        var res: [T] = []
        for card in self {
            res.append(card) <- here I got
```

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

```
        }
        return res
    }

    convenience init<T: Object>(objects: [T]) {
        self.init()
        for card in objects {
            append(card)
        }
    }
}
```

what's a good way to write this adapter once and for all?

Comment: I am curios as to the use case. With the additional of AnyRealmValue, we've found the need for generics to have diminished as now List objects and pretty much store anything without much additional code. e.g. they are not as homogenous as they used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the `where Element`. You can refer to the type of the list items using `Element`, so you do not need to set up another type parameter `T`. `card` is of type `Element` not `T`, so you cannot add it to the `Array<T>`. There is no guarantee that `T` and `Element` are equivalent so the compiler doesn't allow it. The same applies for your convenience init.

```
extension RealmSwift.List where Element == Object {
    // @deprecated use RealmSwift.List<>
    func arrayo() -> [Element] {
        var res: [Element] = []
        for card in self {
            res.append(card) // Now you are adding an `Element` to the array of `Element` so it will work.
        }
        return res
    }

    convenience init(objects: [Element]) {
        self.init()
        for card in objects {
            append(card)
        }
    }
}
```

But generics are not really useful here because you are constraining `Element` to `Object` already. So there is only one potential type - You could make arrayo() and the init use `Object` directly.

To make this useful do

```
extension RealmSwift.List where Elemtn: RealmCollectionValue
```

Comment: How can this be rewritten then to be useable for all objects derived from realm Object?

Comment: @AntonTropashko do you mean how to make the extension usable for all `Element` types? Just remove the `where Element == Object`.

Comment: Yes make the extension usable for all Element types. Removing  where Element == Object brings back the "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"

Comment: @AntonTropashko What line does the error show up on?

Comment: According to the docs, element type must conform to RealmCollectionValue. So try replacing the `where Element == Object` with `where Element : RealmCollectionValue` instead of removing it entirely?